# Groupby() and aggregation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a `pd.DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
In [149]: df
Out[149]: 
   AMOUNT       DATE  ORDER_ID  UID
0    1001 2014-01-02       101    1
1    1002 2014-01-03       102    3
2    1003 2014-01-04       103    4
3    1004 2014-01-05       104    5
4    1005 2014-01-09       105    5
5    1006 2014-01-07       106    7
6    1007 2014-01-08       107    8
7    1008 2014-01-09       108    5
8    1009 2014-01-10       109   10
9    1500 2014-01-09       110    5
```

and I want to truncate all rows that correspond to the same UID and DATE to one row and use the sum of the values in the `AMOUNT` column for the one row that remains.

In short, the desired output would be:

> ```
> In [149]: df
> Out[149]: 
>    AMOUNT       DATE  ORDER_ID  UID
> 0    1001 2014-01-02       101    1
> 1    1002 2014-01-03       102    3
> 2    1003 2014-01-04       103    4
> 3    1004 2014-01-05       104    5
> 4    3513 2014-01-09       105    5 ## <- Rows that previously had index [7,9,4] are now truncated to this one row and the AMOUNT is the sum of of the AMOUNT values of those three rows
> 5    1006 2014-01-07       106    7
> 6    1007 2014-01-08       107    8
> 8    1009 2014-01-10       109   10
> ```

**In essence, what I want to do is 'aggregate' all rows that correspond to the same user UID and DATE to one row and leave all other rows intact.**

What I've tried so far is this:

```
In [154]: df.groupby(['UID','DATE'])['AMOUNT'].sum()
Out[154]: 
UID  DATE      
1    2014-01-02    1001
3    2014-01-03    1002
4    2014-01-04    1003
5    2014-01-05    1004
     2014-01-09    3513
7    2014-01-07    1006
8    2014-01-08    1007
10   2014-01-10    1009
Name: AMOUNT, dtype: int64
```

***but*** I'm not sure where to start in order to either go back to original `df` and remove the 'extra' rows nor how to assign the new sum value of `AMOUNT` to the one remaining row.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the problem with the output you got. Do you want a different index?

Comment: @ayhan thanks for looking into this. I'm not so much interested in the index in fact, just the 'truncating' that I cannot figure out how to do effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['UID','DATE'], as_index=False).agg({'AMOUNT': sum, 'ORDER_ID': 'first'}))

   UID        DATE  AMOUNT  ORDER_ID
0    1  2014-01-02    1001       101
1    3  2014-01-03    1002       102
2    4  2014-01-04    1003       103
3    5  2014-01-05    1004       104
4    5  2014-01-09    3513       105
5    7  2014-01-07    1006       106
6    8  2014-01-08    1007       107
7   10  2014-01-10    1009       109
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this. Seems to me that what you are suggesting is keeping the first row of each group (which is desired), but has no effect on aggregating the `AMOUNT` values of all previous rows.

Comment: sorry, give me a sec

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!

Comment: definitely a better and shorter answer

Comment: Thank you. But if need faster code, ayhan is winner.

Comment: I see now that when there are additional columns in the original `df` they are discarded and only the columns involved in the cmd (`UID`,`DATE`,`AMOUNT`,`ORDER_ID`) remain. Any ideas?

Comment: If add new column, you need aggregate it too so `.agg({'AMOUNT': sum, 'ORDER_ID': 'first', 'new_column': 'first', 'new_column2': sum}))`

Answer (score 2):

```
df['AMOUNT'] = df.groupby(['UID','DATE'])['AMOUNT'].transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates(['UID', 'DATE'])
df
Out[21]: 
   AMOUNT       DATE  ORDER_ID  UID
0    1001 2014-01-02       101    1
1    1002 2014-01-03       102    3
2    1003 2014-01-04       103    4
3    1004 2014-01-05       104    5
4    3513 2014-01-09       105    5
5    1006 2014-01-07       106    7
6    1007 2014-01-08       107    8
8    1009 2014-01-10       109   10
```

Comment: Thanks you, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `aggregate`:

```
In [10]: df.groupby(['UID', 'DATE']).agg({'AMOUNT': np.sum, 'ORDER_ID': lambda x: x.iloc[0]}).reset_index()
Out[10]: 
   UID       DATE  AMOUNT  ORDER_ID
0    1 2014-01-02    1001       101
1    3 2014-01-03    1002       102
2    4 2014-01-04    1003       103
3    5 2014-01-05    1004       104
4    5 2014-01-09    3513       105
5    7 2014-01-07    1006       106
6    8 2014-01-08    1007       107
7   10 2014-01-10    1009       109
```

Assuming you only want the "first" `ORDER_ID` from your expected output, ie. `lambda x: x.iloc[0]`

Comment: Thanks Anzel, that was very helpful.

Comment: @Thanos, not a problem and i'm glad to help. I think jezrael answer is more direct using "sum" and "first"